# Generating function for $\sum_{i=0}^{k} {n \choose i} $

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I'm looking for ordinary generating functions for the above expression.
If it doesn't exist, I'll be open to consider exponential generating functions as well.

Edit: I'm actually trying to simplify the following expression:
$$\sum_{p=1}^{f_{1}} {\left(\left(\sum_{i=0}^{p-1} {f_{2} \choose i}\right) {f_{1}\choose p} \left(\sum_{i=0}^{p}{f_{3}\choose i}\right)\right)}$$
Here, $f_1, f_2$ and $f_3$ are known beforehand.

Comment: Here is a general remark: If $f(x)$ is the generating function for $(a_n)_{n\geq0}$, then $(1-x)^{-1}f(x)$ is the generating function for $\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k$. This follows from $$\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+\dots.$$

Comment: Your remark is very insightful. Thank you.